# Calling "add" method from bootstrap-tag library

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

So I am using a library called bootstrap-tag (not to be confused with bootstrap-tags <-plural). Here is its repository: https://github.com/fdeschenes/bootstrap-tag

I am trying to build the value that the tag will have from other input fields and then from a click of a button, add that tag to the tag-input field.

[image]

I first tried to see if I could access the element's prototype and get the add method from there. But I could only ever get the prototype of a jquery element. Only reason I'm not including code is because I am using Ember.js and don't want that to possibly complicate the actual problem I am having. If it is beneficial for me to include code, let me know and I'll add it to the question.

The tag-input field works perfectly when typing inside of it. How do I build the value from outside of the field and add a tag?

Also the add method I am aiming to use is on this line in the 3rd party library: 
https://github.com/fdeschenes/bootstrap-tag/blob/master/js/bootstrap-tag.js#L136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library doesn't provide an API for this..
But you can hack it easily ;)

```
<input id="test-input" />

var tags = new $.fn.tag.Constructor(document.getElementById('test-input'), {});
tags.add('Hack');
tags.add('it');
tags.add('easily');
```

OR you can do this:

```
var tagsElement = $('.tags-input').tag(options);

addTagToElement(tagsElement, 'Whatever');   

function addTagToElement(el, newTag) {
   var e = $.Event('keydown');
   e.keyCode = 13;
   el.next().val(newTag);
   el.next().trigger(e)
}
```

This library creates a placeholder input next to the first defined, and listen to the keydown even.. So the `addTagToElement` snippet simply simulates this..

Comment: Okay, so this is bringing me so much closer! I am now stuck on an error.
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined" on a line in the bootstrap-tag library. On line 27:

https://github.com/fdeschenes/bootstrap-tag/blob/master/js/bootstrap-tag.js#L27

Comment: @TylerDavis try to put value="" into the input field.. or check if this element exists ;)

Comment: ah silly me. @webdeb I misspelled my Id name in `document.getElementById('')` :)   thanks! It worked!